# Read LINQ results

Tags: arrays, linq, enumerate

I'm writing a small application that will download a .csv file via FTP and read that into Excel in a particular format.

I found the LINQ code snippet below on this site that will read the .csv file into the var 'csv'. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to enumerate the var 'csv' into a string array (which I'll then use to populate the relevant Excel cells).

Can anyone help? Thanks, Gavin

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(lblShowFileName.Text).Select(a => a.Split(','));
var csv = from line in lines select (from piece in line select piece);
```

Comment: Why not open the CSV with Excel directly using the COM Interop objects and then Save out the file as XLS or XLSX? I do no believe you need to enumerate through any collection to do this, Excel will take care of that.

Comment: Are you looking for a 2-dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) extension method to generate `string[]` instead of `IEnumerable<string>`

```
var csv = (from line in lines
           select (from piece in line
                   select piece).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Because you're calling `ToArray()` twice - within inner and outer query, your `csv` variable will be [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) of strings: `string[][]`